# Java backward compatibility explanation

Tags: java, java-7, backwards-compatibility, java-6

I have a java class file. I compiled with JVM 7.  which I implemented java 1.7 additions like String switchcase, diamond operator. Now I want to run this .class file on java 1.6 JRE. Will it run?

A simple program using string switchcase As I uninstalled 6. Please try it out and give me answer

```
  import java.util.Scanner;


  public class Classing 
 {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{


    System.out.println("Enter a month to know who you are");
    System.out.println("Jan \n Feb \n Mar \n Apr");

    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

    String name=scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println(fortune(name.toLowerCase()));

}

public static String fortune(String s)
{


    switch(s)
    {

    case "jan":

        return "Good guy";

   case "feb":

        return "Nice guy";

   case "mar":

      return "Brave guy";

      case "apr":

      return "Super guy";


    }

    return " Month out of option"+s;
}

}
```

Comment: no it wont run..any how you can switch from lower to higher version but from higher to lower version is not possible at some instance. it also depends which classes you have used and are they compatible in lower version??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though this question has an accepted answer, according to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#binary

> The class file version for Java SE 7 is 51, as per the JVM Specification, because of the invokedynamic byte code introduced by JSR 292. Version 51 class files produced by the Java SE 7 compiler cannot be used in Java SE 6.

Comment: Thanks for the ultimate source

Answer (score 4):

Java 7's `switch` on Strings compiles down to the same bytecodes which the Java 6 (and earlier) JRE executes. The same is true of the diamond operator. These are **compiler** features, not **runtime** features.

So while I've never tried, I would expect that if you compile code which uses these features using the Java 7 compiler, it should still run on the Java 6 JRE. Of course, if you try to compile that code using the Java 6 compiler, all you will get is a syntax error.

If you really want to know try it and see!

Comment: Let me try. And it was really interesting though :)

Comment: @seenome : did you try on java 5? Try that too.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with your answer.  See my answer which refers to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#binary

Answer (score 0):

No it will not. Just because of the simple reason that ,JRE7 features are not available on JRE6.

Comment: Since I have it as byte code then why it won't run? It destroys java's platform independent and bytecode definition

Comment: jre interprets the bytecode, so if bytecode contains some instructions which jre6 does not understand as in your case, so error.

Comment: Thanks as this question was asked by my interviewer and I said no. And he said like that it supports backward compatibility. : (

Answer (score 0):

It wont even compile if you just even copy paste the code which you implemented on 1.7 to new class of 1.6 ,because you used  features which was introduced in 1.7 only

Comment: please see my question clearly. I compiled with j7 and having as a class ok

Comment: please dear see my question.